# Failed to Get Full URL in asp.net mvc3 it ignore #

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

how can i get folowing url  
http://localhost:4847/Category/#pageindex=1 
i failed to get full url using Request.Url.OriginalString 
its only give me 
 blocalhost:4847/Category
ignore other paramters. basically i want to get #pageindex=1 from this url
there is any other way to get (#pageindex=1)

Comment: That's right, you can access this URL only in client side code

Comment: But i want to access in server side how it us possible

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using # ? Is it hardcoded ? Why not using Html helper methods to generate the Link urls ?

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Category", "Index", new { pageIndex= "1"})
```

your query string should be like

http://localhost:4847/Category?pageindex=1

Your request for this page will be handled by an Action. So i guess, you should be able to get this as the parameter of that action method.

```
 public ActionResult Index(string pageIndex)
 {
     //do whatver with pageIndex variable value here
 }
```

Comment: Actually i am doing pagination by jquery so when user select any page then its value append in url without loading the page (how pagination is possible by client side)

Comment: @you may need to make an ajax call to get the data for the next page and then reload the grid/ table with that data.

Comment: yes i am doing the ajax call and its is working fine . i want to append this (pageindex) when user refresh or load page it should not lost it search due to ajax

Comment: $.bbq.pushState({ pageIndex: pageIndex }) i use this method for append in url

Comment: it cool bro ..but there is any other way that resplace (#) to (?)